# Add Layer to another Layer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have the following code where I am trying to add a few Kineticjs Layers to another Layer, but when I do nothing shows up at all. I have other shapes added to the canvas which show up fine, and if I add all the layers separately then they appear. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
this.canvas = new Kinetic.Stage({ "container": jQuery( "#testElement" ).get(0),
    "width": ShooterGame.WIDTH, "height": ShooterGame.HEIGHT });

this.container = new Kinetic.Layer();
this.layer1 = new Kinetic.Layer();
this.layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer();
this.layer3 = new Kinetic.Layer();

this.layer1Bg = new Kinetic.Rect({ "width": 100, "height": 100, "fill": "#FF0000" });
this.layer2Bg = new Kinetic.Rect({ "width": 100, "height": 100, "fill": "#FF0000" });
this.layer3Bg = new Kinetic.Rect({ "width": 100, "height": 100, "fill": "#FF0000" });

this.layer1.add( this.layer1Bg );
this.layer2.add( this.layer2Bg );
this.layer3.add( this.layer3Bg );

this.container.add( this.layer1 );
this.container.add( this.layer2 );
this.container.add( this.layer3 );
this.canvas.add( this.container );

this.container.draw();
```

Comment: What's the purpose to put a layer into another one? Group them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add layers to a group (Kinetic.Group) and then add the group to the stage.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing - strange that the documentation doesn't mention this limitation